# Jquery Toggle Button Images

Tags: jquery, button

I have three buttons with images that each have a unique "OFF" image and a unique "ON" (or clicked) image.

DEFAULT ON PAGE LOAD

[ON]   [OFF]    [OFF]

If I hover over button two I want it to be

[ON]   [ON]  [OFF]

And if I select button 2 I want it to be

[OFF]  [ON]  [OFF]

Answer (score 0):

Didn't make the images unique per button, but this illustrates the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/TWbDk/